# Angular unit test with mocked observable not returning value

Tags: angular

my component returns the current shift based on the hour.

```
export class CurrentTimeComponent {
  constructor() {}

  now$: Observable<Date> = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    map(() => new Date()),
    share()
  );

  shift$: Observable<string> = this.now$.pipe(
    map((now) => {
      const hour = now.getHours();
      if (hour < 13) {
        return 'early';
      } else if (hour < 20) {
        return 'late';
      } else {
        return 'night';
      }
    })
  );
}
```

I now want to test the `shift$` and fake the `now$` observable

```
  it('should get late shift', (done) => {
    component.now$ = of(parseISO('2021-04-01T16:00:00Z'));
    component.shift$.subscribe((shift) => {
      expect(shift).toEqual('late');
      done();
    });
  });
```

however, when I debug the test, `shift$` always returns the current Date. Shouldnt it return the mocked one i provide with `of(parseISO(...))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `shift$` Observable gets created when the component is instantiated. And when it's created, it uses the value of `this.now$` *at the time of its creation*, which is the `timer` Observable that `now$` is initialized to.

So in your test, by the time you redefine `component.now$` to be a different Observable, the `shift$` Observable chain has already been built and it's referencing the original `timer` Observable.

To get around this (assuming you can update the component code) you can use [RxJS defer](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/defer) to defer the creation of the `shift$` Observable until the time of subscription rather than when the component is instantiated:

```js
shift$: Observable<string> = defer(() => this.now$.pipe( // <-- wrap this in defer
  map((now) => {
    const hour = now.getHours();
    if (hour < 13) {
      return 'early';
    } else if (hour < 20) {
      return 'late';
    } else {
      return 'night';
    }
  })
));
```

The factory function you pass to `defer` won't get executed until `shift$` is subscribed to. That way, `this.now$` won't be referenced until you subscribe to `shift$`, so you'll have an opportunity to redefine `now$` in your test before `shift$` gets created when you subscribe to it.

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jasmine-demo-test-provider-jgd3dp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) showing this approach. (Open the console to verify that the date defined in the test is the date that's actually being received.)

Comment: thx for your solution. Strange, I thought it would not matter since on creation time I do not have a subscriber, and both are cold observables

Comment: Right, they won't start emitting values until you subscribe to them, but the Observables themselves are already created. It might be clearer if you think of them as just objects. `this.now$.pipe()` just returns an object (that happens to be an Observable), so when you say `shift$ = this.now$.pipe()`, you're immediately executing that `pipe()` method and assigning its return value to `shift$`. If you then reassign `now$` to something else, that won't affect `shift$` because `shift$` has already been assigned—it doesn't re-execute `this.now$.pipe()` when it gets subscribed to.

Comment: yeah makse sense, Mike. thanks for your help :)